# openedge logging framework roll files

Tags: logging, openedge, progress-4gl

We are using the Openedge logging framework and trying to figure out how configure a file rolling setup.
I tried setting up ${t.YYYY}-${t.MM}-${t.DD}-${t.MMM} for testing and see if I would get a new file every minute but the log files do not roll. It just keeps adding to the log which does get created with the right name
"Common.v1.Logging": {
"logLevel": "TRACE",
"filters": [
"myfilter",
{
"name": "NAMED_FILE_WRITER",
"fileName": "../logs/logFile.%t{yyyy}.log",
"appendTo": true
}
]
}

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not currently available in the OpenEdge.Logging code. Please log an idea for it at https://openedge.ideas.aha.io/ so that we can add it to our backlog.

Take a look at the [the doc on custom filters](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-develop-services-122/page/Create-a-custom-filter.html); you can create your own rolling logfile filter.

Comment: I am back at trying to figure the rolling. I think, I need to create a new Builder, not a filterbuilder to get a new instance of the logger. I tried to override the writeto method from the filterbuilder but it is not possible. Do you have an example I could follow?